# Наследование классов PHP

Tags: php, ооп

Можно ли на PHP организовать такую структуру, и если да, то как.

Дано 3 класса A, B и C.

```
class A {
  public $error = array();

  public function errors() {
    foreach ($this->error as $err) {
       echo $err."<br>";
    }
  }
}

class B extends class A {
  public function __construct {
    $this->error[] = "Ошибка 1";
  }
}

class C extends class A {
  public function __construct {
    $this->error[] = "Ошибка 2";
  }
}

$a = new A();
$b = new B();
$c = new C();

$a->errors();
```

как сделать так (что нужно изменить в коде), чтобы результатом этого скрипта стало:

```
Ошибка 1
Ошибка 2
```

Answer (score 0):

```
class A {

    public static $error = [];

    public static function errors() {
        return implode('<br/>', self::$error);
    }

}

class B extends A {

    public function __construct() {
        self::$error[] = "Ошибка 1";    
    }

}

class C extends A {

    public function __construct() {
        self::$error[] = "Ошибка 2";
    }

}

$b = new B();
$c = new C();

echo A::errors();
// Ошибка 1
// Ошибка 2
```

Comment: $a = new A() даже и не нужно

Comment: Нет, это не решает искомую задачу. Нужно сделать так чтобы методы классов B и C работали с одним и тем же экземпляром класса A.

Comment: @Finies обновил ответ

Comment: Вариант использование статических свойств и методов, равно как и передачу экземпляра класса в виде переменной, я рассматривал, но хотелось найти более изящное решение. Пока ещё ищу )

Answer (score 0):

На всякий случай сообщу как решил свою задачу (заодно переписал её убрав опечатки :). Пришлось прибегнуть к вложенному наследованию и работой только с классом C. Это немного изменило суть, зато позволило работать с одним экземпляром класса C, включающем A и B.

```
class A {
  public $error = array();

  public function errors() {
    foreach ($this->error as $err) {
       echo $err."<br>";
    }
  }
}

class B extends A {
  public function __construct() {
    $this->error[] = "Ошибка 1";
  }
}

class C extends B {
  public function __construct() {
    parent::__construct();
    $this->error[] = "Ошибка 2";
  }
}

$c = new C();

$c->errors();
```